# Unable to load Dask data frame -- Expected meta to specify type DataFrame error

Tags: python, dask

I am trying to use Dask to load a fixed width file so I can parse out the columns and load into a database, but I cannot get Dask to load the data frame. I am receiving an error saying the Expected meta to specify type DataFrame, got type pandas.core.frame.DataFrame.

Here is the code:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df == dd.read_csv("S://folder//file.csv")
```

Can anyone assist as to what I can do differently?

Thanks,
phil

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please see the guide to [ask], and especially, make sure to [format](/help/formatting) your code as a code block, and always post the full [traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback) - they're full of information that's critical to debugging. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There was a [bug](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/7168) with the similar behavior, try to update dask to the latest version, e.g. using:

```
pip install dask -U
```

Comment: Yes, I was looking into that now too. If updating dask is not a viable option, it's also possible to downgrade pandas to a suitable version for compatibility as well, although not the best solution.